# Spinner multi-choice in dropdown

Tags: android, spinner

I'm modifying an Android app, and they asked me to create some custom spinners. I made it without problem using an ArrayAdapter, and a Custom view.

But now, they are asking me to make a multi-choice spinner, in a dropdown. Here is what it should looks like:
[image]

So i started looking on google if there is already a multi-choice spinner implement, but It seems hard to find something in dropdown (and not modal) mode. And in addition, make it print 2 columns for options seems just more and more complicated with an ArrayAdapter.

So my question is: should I still use a custom spinner with more customisation to print the buttons etc, or should I create a complete custom views ? If so, how can I create a dropdown popup like in spinners ?

Thanks

Comment: I would probably go with a custom layout using a GridLayoutManager to arrange your views. Create an adapter and manage the selection using a viewmodel or something else.

Comment: @ItzDavi I just created an adapter, and i split each value in 2 to make the row, and then I'm using some custom getter/setter to return a logical value